# how to stop cp: overwrite './xxx' ? prompt

Tags: linux, bash, centos, cp

How can I stop the cp command from prompting to overwrite. I want to overwrite all the files with out having to keep going back to the terminal. As these are large files and take some time to complete.

I tried using the -f option. It still ask if I want to overwrite.

```
   -f, --force
          if an existing destination file cannot be opened, remove it and
          try again (redundant if the -n option is used)

cp -f /media/somedir/somefiles* .  
cp: overwrite `./somefilesxxx'? y
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In addition to calling `/bin/cp`, you could do one of:

```
\cp -f ...
command cp -f ...
```

However, I agree that you should not get accustomed to using an alias like `cp -i` or `rm -i` -- if you sit down at a different shell, you won't have the safety net you've become dependent on.

Comment: A `whereis cp` will show where is the command. So you'll be able to call the real command instead of the alias.

Answer (score 14):

After seeing this solution. I could see that bashes alias feature was causing the problems. 
http://systembash.com/content/prompt-to-confirm-copy-even-with-cp-f/

```
which cp  
alias cp='cp -i'
/bin/cp
which cp | grep cp
alias cp='cp -i'
/bin/cp
```

He recommends

```
unalias cp
```

I still want to keep the alias I just don't want it to apply to this instance. My solution
is to use the binary with a full path, so that bashes alias function does not take over. That works quite well.

```
/bin/cp -f /media/somedir/somefiles* .
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately on Linux the copy "cp" command doesn’t have an option to automatically answer this question with a "y" or "n" answer. There’s more than one solution to this problem depending on what you want to do. One solution is to use the Unix "yes" command. This command will output a string repeatedly until killed.

If we want to overwrite all of the files in the destination directory you can use the "yes" command to answer all questions with a "y". "y" is a default value so it doesn't have to be specified.

```
yes | cp source/*.txt destination/.
```

If we want to avoid overwriting any of the files in the destination directory you can use the "yes" command to answer all questions with a no "n".

```
yes n | cp source/*.txt destination/.
```

Use "man yes" for more information about the "yes" command.